# How to order dataset of a select statement based on the values of its column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
create table Item
(
    Id bigint primary key identity(1,1),
    Status nvarchar(100),
    DateFiled datetime
)

INSERT INTO Item 
VALUES ('CLOSED', '2017-08-23 16:42:32.720'), --1
       ('OPEN', '2017-08-21 16:42:32.720'), --2
       ('OPEN', '2017-08-22 16:42:32.720'), --3
       ('GRABBED', '2017-08-22 16:42:32.720'), --4
       ('CLOSED', '2017-08-21 16:42:32.720'), --5
       ('OPEN', '2017-08-23 16:42:32.720'); --6
```

How to make a single select statement ordered by the following conditions?

- IF(THERE ARE NO GRABBED ITEMS):1 record item with OPEN statuses that are filed earliest should be the first row.
- ELSE: GRABBED items should be first
- Followed by closed items
- Followed by the rest of the open items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate some summary statistics using a subquery and then use that in the `order by`.

If I have the rules correct:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by status order by datefiled) as seqnum,
             sum(case when status = 'GRABBED' then 1 else 0 end) over () as num_grabbed
      from items i
     ) i
order by (case when num_grabbed = 1 and status = 'OPEN' and seqnum = 1
            then 1
            when status = 'GRABBED' then 2
            when status = 'CLOSED' then 3
            else 4
       end);
```

Comment: Is this not possible with a select statement?  I will try to use this when I go back to work, though this would cause some drastic changes to my code since I am building my query using a stringbuilder and refractoring existing code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a conditional `order by` using case. It will sort by the result of the case for each row.

```
order by case when exists (select 1 from Item where status = 'GRABBED')
                  then case
                          when status = 'GRABBED' then 1
                          when status = 'CLOSED' then 2
                          when status = 'OPEN' then 3
                          else 4
                      end       
                  else case
                           when status = 'OPEN' then 1
                           else 2
                       end
              end, 
         DateFiled
```